# how to make a new column by joining to existing column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I know there are a lot of similar type of this question but I can't find my way around through existing answers. It's a simple question but still I am stuck on this small problem. I have a data with lots of columns. I want to create a new column using two of the existing columns. Something like this:

```
Index Date         Time 
0     26-10-2017   06:00:00
1     26-10-2017   06:15:00
2     26-10-2017   06:30:00
```

Now I need a new column which should look like this:

```
Index Date         Time       Datetime
0     26-10-2017   06:00:00   26-10-2017 06:00:00
1     26-10-2017   06:15:00   26-10-2017 06:15:00
2     26-10-2017   06:30:00   26-10-2017 06:30:00
```

I am unable to do that exactly right now. I am currently getting a tuple with two string values but I don't want this:

```
Index Date         Time       Datetime
0     26-10-2017   06:00:00   ('26-10-2017', '06:00:00')
1     26-10-2017   06:15:00   ('26-10-2017', '06:15:00')
2     26-10-2017   06:30:00   ('26-10-2017', '06:30:00')
```

I am using the following code:

```
df5['Datetime'] = list(zip(df5.Date, df5.Time))
```

Is there anyway I can just get the value the way I want not in tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming columns are strings, add them up and use `pd.to_datetime`

```
df.assign(DateTime=pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time))

   Index        Date      Time            DateTime
0      0  26-10-2017  06:00:00 2017-10-26 06:00:00
1      1  26-10-2017  06:15:00 2017-10-26 06:15:00
2      2  26-10-2017  06:30:00 2017-10-26 06:30:00
```

Comment: Yes it worked! I just had to make my one column string other was already a string. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need `sum` converted column `Date` [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and column `Time` [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.Time = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time)
df['Datetime'] = df.Date + df.Time
print (df)
            Date     Time            Datetime
Index                                        
0     2017-10-26 06:00:00 2017-10-26 06:00:00
1     2017-10-26 06:15:00 2017-10-26 06:15:00
2     2017-10-26 06:30:00 2017-10-26 06:30:00

print (df.dtypes)
Date         datetime64[ns]
Time        timedelta64[ns]
Datetime     datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```